# How to remove z-index property using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website in which there are **4 divs of equal dimensions**. If I **click** any div it would **maximize to cover the remaining 3 divs**. To achieve this I need to use **z-index** property. I do not specify z-index in the style and only add it using jQuery when I click any div. Here is my code for a div:

```
<div id="one" style="background: #58D3F7; height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute;
    margin-left: 410px; margin-top: 202px; float: left; cursor: pointer; text-align: center;"></div>
```

And here is jQuery code for maximizing:

```
$(function () {
    var state = true;
    $("#one").click(function () {
        if (state) {
            $("#one").animate({
                height: 300,
                top: -100
            }, 1000);
            $("#one").css({ "z-index": "1" });
            $("#one").animate({
                width: 300,
                left: -100
            }, 1000);
            $("#itxt1").animate({
                color: "#58D3F7"
            }, 1000);
            $("#one").animate({
                height: 650,
                width: 650
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#one").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#58D3F7",
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                left: 8,
                top: 8,
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
            $("#one").removeAttr("z-index");
        }
        state = !state;
    });
});
```

The above code works fine except when I click the div second time to minimize it, the z-index property remains. I want it to go. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks guys it is working fine. But i am facing another issue..it happens instantly i.e. as soon as i click the div, the z-index property vanishes and the remaining divs show on top of this one. Can i time that property like i did for minimizing the div?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The z-index isn't an attribute.

As stated in the documentation, you can do

```
$("#one").css("z-index", '');
```

Extract from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) :

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property. It does not, however, remove a
>   style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or 
>   element.

Comment: you could also use ```$("#one").css("z-index", 'unset');``` to be explicit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Answer (score 5):

Use initial to reset z-index back to its default value

```
$('#id').css('z-index','initial');
```

**CSS Syntax**

z-index: auto|number|initial|inherit;

- **auto**:    Sets the stack order equal to its parents. This is default
- **number**:  Sets the stack order of the element. Negative numbers are allowed
- **initial**: Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial
- **inherit**: Inherits this property from its parent element.

Comment: I think, this is the only correct answer to this question. All others will not remove the attribute, if it is set in a css-file. You could use 'unset' instead of 'initial', too. But not tested in IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove using `.css()` in jQuery

```
$('#id').css('z-index','');
```

try like this

Comment: Setting it to 0 won't remove the z-index completely.

Comment: it is working fine now.but it happens instantly. I mean when i click the div the other 3 divs immeadiately shows on top of the current div. I want it to happen after the div has minimized.how can i do this?

Comment: you can call this using click event

Comment: i tried giving like this:  $("#one").css({"z-index","0"},3000) so that it happens after some time but it gives error

Comment: use this $('#one').css('z-index','');

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$("#one").removeAttr("z-index");
```

Remove it from the CSS:

```
$("#one").css("z-index", "");
```

Or, perhaps

```
$("#one").css("z-index", "auto");
```